# Javascript validation: Block special characters

Tags: javascript, validation

How can I restrict users from entering special characters in the text box. I want only numbers and alphabets to be entered ( Typed / Pasted ).

Any samples?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two approaches to this:

1. check the "keypress" event. If the user presses a special character key, stop him right there
2. check the "onblur" event: when the input element loses focus, validate its contents. If the value is invalid, display a discreet warning beside that input box.

I would suggest the second method because its less irritating. Remember to also check `onpaste` . If you use only keypress Then We Can Copy and paste special characters so use `onpaste` also to restrict Pasting special characters

Additionally, I will also suggest that you reconsider if you really want to prevent users from entering special characters. Because many people have $, #, @ and * in their passwords.

I presume that this might be in order to prevent SQL injection; if so: its better that you handle the checks server-side. Or better still, escape the values and store them in the database.

Comment: Limiting input isn't necessarily restrictive, it might be to input phone numbers, Zip codes, dates, etc.
But +1 to the advice to double the checking on server side!

Answer (score 21):

Try this one, this function allows alphanumeric and spaces:

```
function alpha(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

in your html:

```
<input type="text" name="name"  onkeypress="return alpha(event)"/>
```

Comment: Why are you testing `document.all` to determine support for `e.keyCode`? Why not test `e.keyCode` instead?

Comment: Technically you don't need any grouping parentheses; `&&` takes precedence over `||`.

Comment: This works but what if we want to allow user to input . and ,

Comment: this allows spaces (k== 32) --> i think it is one of the "special characters" to be excluded in my understanding

Answer (score 8):

For special characters:

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

for (var i = 0; i < document.formname.fieldname.value.length; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(document.formname.fieldname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        alert ("Your username has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n Please remove them and try again.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It would help you... assume you have a form with "formname" form and a text box with "txt" name. then you can use following code to allow only aphanumeric values

```
var checkString = document.formname.txt.value;
if (checkString != "") {
    if ( /[^A-Za-z\d]/.test(checkString)) {
        alert("Please enter only letter and numeric characters");
        document.formname.txt.focus();
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, just use an appropriate onkeypress handler.  See http://www.qodo.co.uk/blog/javascript-restrict-keyboard-character-input/ and the example http://www.qodo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/javascript-restrict-keyboard-character-input.html

Answer (score 2):

I think checking `keypress` events is not completely adequate, as I believe users can **copy/paste** into input boxes without triggering a keypress.

So `onblur` is probably somewhat more reliable (but is less immediate).

To truly make sure characters you don't want are not entered into input boxes (or textareas, etc.), I think you will need to

1. check `keypress` (if you want to give immediate feedback) and
2. also check `onblur`,
3. as well as validating inputs on the server (which is the only real way to make sure nothing unwanted gets into your data).

The code samples in the other answers will work fine for doing the client-side checks (just don't rely *only* on checking `keypress` events), but as was pointed out in the accepted answer, a server-side check is really required.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the options are deprecated as of today. So watch out for those.

If you try `<input onkeypress="blockSpecialCharacters(event)" />`, an IDE like `WebStorm` will slash out <s>event</s> and tell you:

> Deprecated symbol used, consults docs for better alternative

Then when you get to the JavaScript, `console.log(e.keyCode)` will also give <s>keyCode</s> and say:

> Deprecated symbol used, consults docs for better alternative

Anyways I did it using jQuery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

<input id="theInput" />

<script>
    function blockSpecialCharacters(e) {
            let key = e.key;
            let keyCharCode = key.charCodeAt(0);

            // 0-9
            if(keyCharCode >= 48 && keyCharCode <= 57) {
                return key;
            }
            // A-Z
            if(keyCharCode >= 65 && keyCharCode <= 90) {
                return key;
            }
            // a-z
            if(keyCharCode >= 97 && keyCharCode <= 122) {
                return key;
            }

            return false;
    }

    $('#theInput').keypress(function(e) {
        blockSpecialCharacters(e);
    });
</script>
```