# How to avoid entering special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

On html I have one input box in which I just want to enter numeric values. I used following function:

```
function allowNumbersOnly(event,locale) {
    if(locale=='en' && (event.keyCode==190 || event.keyCode==110)){
        return true;
    }
    else if(locale=='nl' && (event.keyCode==188 || event.keyCode==190 || event.keyCode==110)){
        return true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode==189 || (event.keyCode==109) ){
        return true;
    }
    var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode || 0;

    // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
    if (
        key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 46 ||
        (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105)){

        }else{
             event.preventDefault();

            }
}
```

This code works fine. But when I am pressing `shift key+ any number` from keyboard then special character gets entered. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try using html5 pattern attribute

Comment: For HTML 5, use type="number"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following function

```
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

If you are using **HTML5** just try

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Thanks Aishwarya. Your code helped me in my issue. I modified your code as follows:                                                              `function isNumber(evt) {
     evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
     if (charCode > 31 && charCode != 44 && charCode != 46 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
         return false;
     }
     return true;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906190/javascript-validation-block-special-characters/6400280#6400280):

```
function blockspecialcharacter(e) {
    var key= document.all ? key= e.keyCode : key= e.which;
    return ((key > 64 && key < 91) || (key> 96 && key< 123) || key== 8 || key== 32 || (key>= 48 && key<= 57));
}
```

[Check demo here](http://jsbin.com/zohoceki/1/)

Comment: the first two lines can be shortened to `var k = document.all?e.keyCode: e.which;` or just `var k = e.keyCode || e.which`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't include the special characters on the Num Key Pad.

Answer (score 0):

shiftKey event attribute returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not the "SHIFT" key was pressed

```
if (event.shiftKey==1)
{
    alert("The shift key was pressed!")
}
else
{
    alert("The shift key was NOT pressed!")
}
```

so you can exit from your function if shift is pressed using value of event.shiftKey

```
// in your code
function allowNumbersOnly(event,locale) {
    if (event.shiftKey==1) {
        return false;
    } // RETURN if shift key got clicked.

    if (locale=='en' && (event.keyCode==190 || event.keyCode==110)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (locale=='nl' && (event.keyCode == 188 ||
                              event.keyCode == 190 ||
                              event.keyCode == 110)) {

        return true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode==189 || (event.keyCode==109)) {
        return true;
    }

    var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode || 0;

    // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
    if (key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 46 ||
        (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105)) {

    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function blockSpecialChars(e){
    var e = e || window.event;
    var k = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var s = String.fromCharCode(k);
    return !/^[\\\"\'\;\:\>\|~`!@#\$%^&*\(\)]$/i.test(s);
}
```

Add or remove the special characters from the above code to make it as you need.