# Prevent special chars in text area

Tags: javascript, textarea

I need to prevent special characters to being inserted in the text area. It should work across all browsers.

I've tried to do it but it won't check "~" and "ã" and "á". In this case "ã" get same code as "a".

```js
   $('#sms_text').keydown(function(e) {if((e.keyCode>64 && e.keyCode<91) || (e.keyCode>96 && e.keyCode<123) || e.keyCode==8)
                {}
             else{e.preventDefault();}});
   $('#sms_text').keyup(function(e){if((e.keyCode>64 && e.keyCode<91) || (e.keyCode>96 && e.keyCode<123) || e.keyCode==8)
             {}
             else{e.preventDefault();}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" style="width:40%">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="sms_text"></textarea>
    <div class="text-right">
    <h6 class="badge badge-dark"><span id="count_message">0</span>/50</h6>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I should expect prevent in that special cases.

Comment: Is it possible to check for the character as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript validation: Block special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906190/javascript-validation-block-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the jQuery alphanumeric plugin! [enter link description here](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum)

```
//All of these are from their demo page
//only numbers and alpha characters
$('.sample1').alphanumeric();
//only numeric
$('.sample4').numeric();
//only numeric and the .
$('.sample5').numeric({allow:"."});
//all alphanumeric except the . 1 and a
$('.sample6').alphanumeric({ichars:'.1a'});
```

Comment: how should I install without using npm or other? (just files)

Answer (score 0):

```
let textAreaContainer = $('#sms_text');
textAreaContainer.keyup(function(e){
if (e != "") {
    if ( /[^\w\d]/.test(e)) {
        alert("Please enter only letter and numeric characters");
        return (false);
    } else { e.preventDefault()}
}
})
```

this expression match 
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\w\d]

- \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

or may be a solution with ur approach with this condition on the if

```
((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57) || k == 190 || k == 188)
```

Comment: checkString not defined? did you try?

Comment: check it again now

Comment: its not working it allows every char but shows alert every time