# Want to allow Backspace or spcae button using js

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this script to restrict all Special Characters but i only want to allow Backspace(8) and space(32) key.

```js
var specialKeys = new Array();
//specialKeys.push(8);  //Backspace
specialKeys.push(9);  //Tab
specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
specialKeys.push(36); //Home
specialKeys.push(35); //End
specialKeys.push(37); //Left
specialKeys.push(39); //Right

function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}
```

```html
<input name="pname" list="pnames" id="pname" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required/>
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special characters are not allowed.</span>
```

Please help how can I do that..
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906190/javascript-validation-block-special-characters, you can take this as a reference and work on from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    var ret = ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
    }
```

```html
<input name="pname" list="pnames" id="pname" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required/>
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special characters are not allowed.</span>
```